# Creating Instances of IronPython Classes From C#

Tags: c#, .net, python, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

I want to create an instance of an IronPython class from C#, but my current attempts all seem to have failed.

This is my current code:

```
ConstructorInfo[] ci = type.GetConstructors();

foreach (ConstructorInfo t in from t in ci
                              where t.GetParameters().Length == 1
                              select t)
{
    PythonType pytype = DynamicHelpers.GetPythonTypeFromType(type);
    object[] consparams = new object[1];
    consparams[0] = pytype;
    _objects[type] = t.Invoke(consparams);
    pytype.__init__(_objects[type]);
    break;
}
```

I am able to get the created instance of the object from calling t.Invoke(consparams), but the `__init__` method doesn't seem to be called, and thus all the properties that I set from my Python script aren't used. Even with the explicit `pytype.__init__` call, the constructed object still doesn't seem to be initialised.

Using ScriptEngine.Operations.CreateInstance doesn't seem to work, either.

I'm using .NET 4.0 with IronPython 2.6 for .NET 4.0.

**EDIT**: Small clarification on how I'm intending to do this:

In C#, I have a class as follows:

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static object Instantiate(Type type)
    {
        // do the instantiation here
    }
}
```

And in Python, the following code:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "this should be called"

Foo.Instantiate(MyClass)
```

The `__init__` method never seems to be called.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instantiating a python class in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579272/instantiating-a-python-class-in-c)

Comment: After taking a look at the IronPython source, the \__init__ method is defined as public void __init__(object o) { }. Whoops.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code works with IronPython 2.6.1

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string script = @"
class A(object) :
    def __init__(self) :
        self.a = 100

class B(object) : 
    def __init__(self, a, v) : 
        self.a = a
        self.v = v
    def run(self) :
        return self.a.a + self.v
";

        var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
        var scope = engine.CreateScope();
        engine.Execute(script, scope);

        var typeA = scope.GetVariable("A");
        var typeB = scope.GetVariable("B");
        var a = engine.Operations.CreateInstance(typeA); 
        var b = engine.Operations.CreateInstance(typeB, a, 20);
        Console.WriteLine(b.run()); // 120
    }
```

**EDITED according to clarified question**

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            var scriptScope = engine.CreateScope();

            var foo = new Foo(engine);

            scriptScope.SetVariable("Foo", foo);
            const string script = @"
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print ""this should be called""

Foo.Create(MyClass)
";
            var v = engine.Execute(script, scriptScope);
        }
    }

public  class Foo
{
    private readonly ScriptEngine engine;

    public Foo(ScriptEngine engine)
    {
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    public  object Create(object t)
    {
        return engine.Operations.CreateInstance(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that I'm not using `scope.GetVariable` -- I'm passing the types directly to C# in the form of the C# `Type` class, mainly because I need to call the function from all sorts of places and the variable might not necessarily be available in that scope.

Comment: Even though I answered my own question, I still think you deserve to be the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved my own question -- using the .NET `Type` class seems to have discarded Python type information.

Replacing it with `IronPython.Runtime.Types.PythonType` works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're looking for the answer given to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579272/instantiating-a-python-class-in-c).

Comment: The answers never actually said anything about instantiating the object -- the Calculator class in the example has no constructor method and thus it doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: That SO Q's solution works fine for me, and adding an `__init__` method does get it executed (using the `.Operations` instance as shown there). I don't have a .NET 4.0 to try, but I'd be astonished if they broke things in the 4.0 transition.

Comment: That example isn't entirely suited for me, since I'm passing the type itself to C# code, rather than a scoped variable, i.e. via a function, which might be why the `__init__` method isn't called.