# instantiate python class into C# using the class name as string

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython, cross-language

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579272/instantiating-a-python-class-in-c-sharp?lq=1) SO question provides code to create an instance of a python class in C#.

The following code forces to know the python function name in advance. However I need to specify the class name and the function name to be executed by strings.

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("Calculator.py");
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
source.Execute(scope);

dynamic class_object = scope.GetVariable("Calculator");
dynamic class_instance = class_object();
int result = class_instance.add(4, 5);  // I need to call the function by a string
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do that is to install nuget package called `Dynamitey`. It was designed specifically to call dynamic methods (and doing other useful things) on dynamic objects. After you install it, just do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("Calculator.py");
    ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
    source.Execute(scope);

    dynamic class_object = scope.GetVariable("Calculator");
    dynamic class_instance = class_object();
    int result = Dynamic.InvokeMember(class_instance, "add", 4, 5);
}
```

If you want to know what it does under the hood - it uses the same code which is used by C# compiler for dynamic invocations. This is a long story but if you want to read about this, you can do it [here](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2010/03/c-40-dynamic-keyword-for-dummies-under.html) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the Invoke and InvokeMember IronPython methods:

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile("Calculator.py");
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
source.Execute(scope);

object class_object = scope.GetVariable("Calculator");
object class_instance = engine.Operations.Invoke(class_object);
object[] args = new object[2];
args[0] = 4;
args[1] = 5;
int result = (int)engine.Operations.InvokeMember(class_instance, "add", args);  // Method called by string
                                                                                //  "args" is optional for methods which don't require arguments.
```

I also changed the `dynamic` type to `object`, since you won't need it anymore for this code sample, but you are free to keep it, should you need to call some fixed-name methods.