# Instantiating a python 3.6 class in C#

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x, ironpython

I'm trying to find a way to create an instance of a Python class in C#
I came across [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) and this question:
[Instantiating a python class in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579272/instantiating-a-python-class-in-c-sharp])

However, looking closely it seems it's only designed for Python 2.7, and I couldn't find anything for 3.6 .

Is there something that allows me to use 3.6 Python classes in C#?

Comment: IronPython stable only supports 2.7, there's an unstable version for Python 3.x but it's not production ready

Comment: @UnholySheep Are there any alternatives to IronPython? also, where can I find the unstable version?   I don't see it on their download page

Comment: @Shtut have you tried pythonnet?